# Base 64 Attachment in PHP Mail() not working

Tags: php, email, attachment, mime

[image]

I got a script which sends out an automated email when a function runs. I want to be able to send the HTML email along with a PDF attachment. I know I need to encode the file in to Base64 however I am just getting base64 code attached to the bottom of my email. I assume it's something to do with the mime stuff. Anyone see the issue?

```
    $to = 'example@example.com';

    $subject = 'test!';

    $file = file_get_contents("files/CAPS-Standing-Order.pdf");
    $encoded_file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));

    // message
    $boundary = md5("sanwebe");

    $message = 'Hello';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Additional headers
    $headers .= 'From: CAPS Consortium <contact@capsconsortium.com>' . "\r\n";

    $message .= "--$boundary\r\n";
    $message .="Content-Type: pdf; name=\"CAPS-Standing-Order.pdf\"\r\n";
    $message .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"CAPS-Standing-Order.pdf\"\r\n";
    $message .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $message .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $encoded_file; 

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: simple: don't build your own mime emails. use a proper mail package like swiftmailer or phpmailer. all of that header/encode/split business will be reduced to a single `->addAttachment('somefile.pdf')`, and you can get on with more important things, like getting more coffee.

Comment: `$headers .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed;boundary=\"".$boundary."\"";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents("files/CAPS-Standing-Order.pdf");
$encoded_file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));

$attachments[] = array(
    'name' => 'CAPS-Standing-Order.pdf', // Set File Name
    'data' => $encoded_file, // File Data
    'type' => 'application/pdf', // Type
    'encoding' => 'base64' // Content-Transfer-Encoding
);

$this->sendMail("example@example.com", "Hello", "test!", $attachments); 
// Send the actual mail and include the attachments
```

The function I made to send cleaner mail

```
<?php
function sendMail($email = "", $text = "", $subject = "", $attachments = array()) {
    if(!$email || !$text) {
        return false;
    }

    $headers   = array();
    $headers[] = "To: {$email}";
    $headers[] = "From: CAPS Consortium <contact@capsconsortium.com>";
    $headers[] = "Reply-To: CAPS Consortium <contact@capsconsortium.com>";
    $headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
    $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";

    if(!empty($attachments)) {
        $boundary = md5(time());
        $headers[] = "Content-type: multipart/mixed;boundary=\"".$boundary."\"";
        // Have attachment, different content type and boundary required.
    } else {
        $headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    }

    $html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>CAPS Consortium</title>
            <style>table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }</style>
        </head>
        <body style="font-family: arial;" width="100%">
            [text]
        </body>
    </html>';

    $generated = date('jS M Y H:i:s');
    $subject = ($subject ? $subject : 'Default Subject');
    $message = $html;

    $message = str_replace("[text]", $text, $message);

    if(!empty($attachments)) {
        $output   = array();
        $output[] = "--".$boundary;
        $output[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"";
        $output[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
        $output[] = "";
        $output[] = $message;
        $output[] = "";
        foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
            $output[] = "--".$boundary;
            $output[] = "Content-Type: ".$attachment['type']."; name=\"".$attachment['name']."\";";
            if(isset($attachment['encoding'])) {
                $output[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: " . $attachment['encoding'];
            }
            $output[] = "Content-Disposition: attachment;";
            $output[] = "";
            $output[] = $attachment['data'];
            $output[] = "";
        }
        return mail($email, $subject, implode("\r\n", $output), implode("\r\n", $headers));
    } else {
        return mail($email, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
    }

}
```

Hopefully this helps. Shouldn't require too much explanation as it's pretty much what you have, just cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: Scrap that was getting a cached result. The above script will put the email HTML in the attachment of a .txt file and the attachment header and Base64 as the email body. However moving the output of the body above the attachment puts the html and attachment the right way however it will just display the text.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/adish6 = example. http://pastebin.com/kJN8Jcxm = current state of the function.

Comment: Try type of application/pdf instead of pdf in attachment array?

Comment: FYI if you dont pass the attachments into the function it works fine. I assume the issue lies within `if(!empty($attachments)) {}`

Comment: Aye, let me try sending a PDF, un momento.

Comment: Let me paste my full script for you including the full HTML markup.

Comment: Change attachment to what I have, and add the lines I added `if(isset($attachment['encoding'])) {
                $output[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: " . $attachment['encoding'];
            }` inside too.

Comment: http://imgur.com/PbbGAE1 Using your Email HTML, what I get through my local server.

Comment: what the f**k... Like I said before it looks solid I just can't understand why it doesn't work. Must be some settings.

Comment: Hi I tried the same code on a fresh insall of CentOS and it worked fine. Must be server settings. I can confirm this is the fix. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: To be fair, I just updated this a little, I believe by switching this part: http://pastebin.com/jZcWRH0v  might fix it in future issues.